# Get the menu name or location of current menu item

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem

I am having a hard time trying to get the name of the active menu and, apparently, I cannot find any solutions to this issue. Basically, I have several menus that follow this pattern:

**Menu Name**

- Menu Item 1
- Menu Item 2
- ...
- Menu Item n

I want to display the menu name of the current page item, but I cannot find any way of doing it. I have tried using get_nav_menu_locations() in conjunction with get_term():

```
$theme_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu_obj = get_term($theme_locations["menu_1"], 'nav_menu');
$menu_name = $menu_obj->name;
```

However, I need to get the location of the current menu dynamically and after searching for answers/solutions and not finding anything concrete, I just assume that there may be at least a database relationship between the current menu item and the menu object to which is assigned; from where I would eventually get the menu location/term ID.

PS: I want to output the active menu title without the use of JS

Answer (score 0):

I coded a solution to highlight the current active hyperlink in a menu within WordPress. It's a simple PHP snippet that checks to see if you are on a specified page ID.

**Example #1:**

```
<?php if (is_page(2) || is_page(25)){ ?> OUTPUT CLASS HERE, MENU NAME (Menu Item 1, Menu Item 2) OR ANYTHING ELSE<?php } ?>
```

**Example #2 (How I used it):**

```
<li class="nav_b<?php if (is_page(2) || is_page(25) || is_page(27) || is_page(30) || is_page(31)){ ?> current_page_item<?php } ?>"><a rel="external nofollow" class="app_tickets<?php if (is_page(2) || is_page(25) || is_page(27) || is_page(30) || is_page(31)){ ?> active<?php } ?>" href="/example-url/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Tickets', 'Click', 'B', 1, false]);" title="Example Title">Example Hyperlink</a></li>
```

You can easily modified it to output the menu's name!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. It is not a flexible solution since new pages are prone to be added constantly and editing the files each time does not make it dynamic in the end. Plus that the client for which I am building the website in question is a simple end user. In any case, thank you for taking the time!